# Postponing window.location to allow time for AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, window.location

I have an index page which I'd like to use to set up a local database before moving on to another page. However, whenever I have the window.location code activated none of the other functions run, but when I comment it out the other functions run fine. Any ideas to what would be causing this and how I can get both the functions and the window.locations to work? Code is as follows:

```
<script>
        var db = window.openDatabase("DB1", "", "DB", 1024 * 1000)
            CreateDB(); //Creates local database tables
            loadRouteList(); //Queries web server database using AJAX and inserts Routes
            window.location = 'Application.html';
</script>
```

Functions Used:

```
function CreateDB() {
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Routes(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, routeID TEXT, customerID TEXT, stopSeq TEXT, driverID TEXT)', []);
    });
};
function loadRouteList() {
var dataObject = {
    postDesignator: 'routes',
};
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://url.php',
    data: dataObject,
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'post',
    success: function (Result) {
        for (var i = 0, len = Result.records.length; i < len; ++i) {
            var route = Result.records[i].record;
            insertRoute(route.routeID, null, null, null);
        }
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Your "load" functions probably initiate asynchronous activity. You need to defer the page reload to the point at which the HTTP requests have completed. Exactly how you do that depends on the code you're using.

Comment: the ajax requests you're firing immediately before setting window.location aren't going to get back before the page starts loading Application.html, but they should still fire though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, AJAX is `Asynchronous`, so if you run those functions and you don't wait them to be completed, your code will go on without waiting them. So you arrive at the point that your location changes due to your line. You have to wait until all your requests are done before going on, and to do this you have to change the code inside your functions. If you post them we could help you.

**EDIT**

In my opinion, the best way to do it is to pass a callback to your function:

```
function CreateDB() {
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Routes(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, routeID TEXT, customerID TEXT, stopSeq TEXT, driverID TEXT)', []);
    });
    //if even this piece of code is async you should read docs and check how to call a function after the query executed
};
function loadRouteList(callback) {
    var dataObject = {
        postDesignator: 'routes',
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://url.php',
        data: dataObject,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'post',
        success: function (Result) {
            for (var i = 0, len = Result.records.length; i < len; ++i) {
                var route = Result.records[i].record;
                insertRoute(route.routeID, null, null, null);
            }
            if(callback) {
                callback();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And then use it this way:

```
var db = window.openDatabase("DB1", "", "DB", 1024 * 1000)
    CreateDB(); //Creates local database tables
    loadRouteList(function() {
        window.location = 'Application.html';
    });
```

Comment: Okay I see. What's the best way to postpone the window.location request? I added the two functions that get used.

Comment: Are those functions in the same page/script? Is executeSql async?

Comment: thanks for not stealing my code. give me at least an upvote in favor ;)

Comment: LOL I hadn't checked new entries, I was editing my answer after my comment, if you want I can remove/change my(yours lol) code, no problem! ;)

Comment: nah, leave it ;) go get the rep points :D you wrote at least some meaningfull sentences ;)

Answer (score 2):

use callbacks! I modified your code:

```
<script>
    var db = window.openDatabase("DB1", "", "DB", 1024 * 1000);
    CreateDB(); //Creates local database tables
    loadRouteList(function() { window.location = 'Application.html'} );
</script>
```

Functions Used:

```
function CreateDB() {
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Routes(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, routeID TEXT, customerID TEXT, stopSeq TEXT, driverID TEXT)', []);
    });
};
function loadRouteList(callback) {
    var dataObject = {
        postDesignator: 'routes',
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://url.php',
        data: dataObject,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'post',
        success: function (Result) {
            for (var i = 0, len = Result.records.length; i < len; ++i) {
                var route = Result.records[i].record;
                insertRoute(route.routeID, null, null, null);
            }
            // this is the so called callback, that gets executed AFTER the ajax has finished
            if(callback) { callback(); }
        }
    });
}
```